# python: can't open file 'manage.py' when I create django app

Tags: python, terminal

I created a project named testdj, and under the directory `/tmp/python-test/testdj/testdj/`, I want to create a django app, so I use the below command:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:testdj ldl$ python manage.py startapp TestModel
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But the the upper error, `can't open file 'manage.py'` there.

I find the stack overflow, there is some the same error, but they are not when creating app occurs.

Comment: Don't put your code under `/tmp`, it'll be wiped the next time you restart your machine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, thanks your advice,and by the way. If I create a project named `testPro`, you know it will generate the `/testPro/testPro` like this directory hierarchy, and if I create the APP, should I under the `/testPro` or `/testPro/testPro`? I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you are using django app,

so first

```
pip install django
django-admin startproject project_name
django-admin startapp app_name

python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Yes, yes, thank you, the tutorial is `python manage.py` I don't know why.